# Run multiple jobs at a time per node through SLURM

Tags: slurm

I have a cluster I am using which has 3 nodes with 110GB of RAM each, and on each node there are 16 cores.  I want to keep submmitting jobs to the nodes as long as the memory specified is available.

I am using this bash script called `test_slurm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=10G
python test.py
```

So if I have 33 10gb jobs, and I have 3 nodes with 110gb of RAM I want to be able to run all 33 at once if possible instead of only 3 at once which is what my current setup does.

This is what by squeue looks like:
[image]

So only three jobs run at once even though I have plenty of memory for more.

`sinfo -o "%all"` returns:

```
    AVAIL|CPUS|TMP_DISK|FEATURES|GROUPS|SHARE|TIMELIMIT|MEMORY|HOSTNAMES|NODE_ADDR|PRIORITY|ROOT|JOB_SIZE|STATE|USER|VERSION|WEIGHT|S:C:T|NODES(A/I) |MAX_CPUS_PER_NODE |CPUS(A/I/O/T) |NODES |REASON |NODES(A/I/O/T) |GRES |TIMESTAMP |DEFAULTTIME |PREEMPT_MODE |NODELIST |CPU_LOAD |PARTITION |PARTITION |ALLOCNODES |STATE |USER |SOCKETS |CORES |THREADS
    up|16|0|(null)|all|NO|infinite|115328|parrot101|parrot101|1|no|1-infinite|alloc|Unknown|14.03|1|16:1:1|1/0 |UNLIMITED |16/0/0/16 |1 |none |1/0/0/1 |(null) |Unknown |n/a |OFF |parrot101 |0.01 |myNodes* |myNodes |all |allocated |Unknown |16 |1 |1
    up|16|0|(null)|all|NO|infinite|115328|parrot102|parrot102|1|no|1-infinite|alloc|Unknown|14.03|1|16:1:1|1/0 |UNLIMITED |16/0/0/16 |1 |none |1/0/0/1 |(null) |Unknown |n/a |OFF |parrot102 |0.14 |myNodes* |myNodes |all |allocated |Unknown |16 |1 |1
    up|16|0|(null)|all|NO|infinite|115328|parrot103|parrot103|1|no|1-infinite|alloc|Unknown|14.03|1|16:1:1|1/0 |UNLIMITED |16/0/0/16 |1 |none |1/0/0/1 |(null) |Unknown |n/a |OFF |parrot103 |0.26 |myNodes* |myNodes |all |allocated |Unknown |16 |1 |1
```

The output of `squeue -o "%all"`

returns:

```
ACCOUNT|GRES|MIN_CPUS|MIN_TMP_DISK|END_TIME|FEATURES|GROUP|SHARED|JOBID|NAME|COMMENT|TIMELIMIT|MIN_MEMORY|REQ_NODES|COMMAND|PRIORITY|QOS|REASON||ST|USER|RESERVATION|WCKEY|EXC_NODES|NICE|S:C:T|JOBID |EXEC_HOST |CPUS |NODES |DEPENDENCY |ARRAY_JOB_ID |GROUP |SOCKETS_PER_NODE |CORES_PER_SOCKET |THREADS_PER_CORE |ARRAY_TASK_ID |TIME_LEFT |TIME |NODELIST |CONTIGUOUS |PARTITION |PRIORITY |NODELIST(REASON) |START_TIME |STATE |USER |SUBMIT_TIME |LICENSES |CORE_SPECWORK_DIR
    (null)|(null)|1|0|N/A|(null)|j1101|no|26609|slurm_py_submit.sh|(null)|UNLIMITED|40K||/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python/slurm_py_submit.sh 1 rcp85 26|0.99998411652632|(null)|Resources||PD|spotter5|(null)|(null)||0|*:*:*|26609 |n/a |1 |1 | |26609 |61101 |* |* |* |N/A |UNLIMITED |0:00 | |0 |myNodes |4294899076 |(Resources) |2019-03-19T13:03:57 |PENDING |474609391 |2018-03-19T11:57:39 |(null) |0/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python
    (null)|(null)|1|0|N/A|(null)|j1101|no|26610|slurm_py_submit.sh|(null)|UNLIMITED|40K||/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python/slurm_py_submit.sh 1 rcp85 27|0.99998411629349|(null)|Resources||PD|spotter5|(null)|(null)||0|*:*:*|26610 |n/a |1 |1 | |26610 |61101 |* |* |* |N/A |UNLIMITED |0:00 | |0 |myNodes |4294899075 |(Resources) |2019-03-19T13:03:57 |PENDING |474609391 |2018-03-19T11:57:39 |(null) |0/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python
    (null)|(null)|1|0|N/A|(null)|j1101|no|26611|slurm_py_submit.sh|(null)|UNLIMITED|40K||/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python/slurm_py_submit.sh 1 rcp85 28|0.99998411606066|(null)|Resources||PD|spotter5|(null)|(null)||0|*:*:*|26611 |n/a |1 |1 | |26611 |61101 |* |* |* |N/A |UNLIMITED |0:00 | |0 |myNodes |4294899074 |(Resources) |2019-03-19T13:03:57 |PENDING |474609391 |2018-03-19T11:57:39 |(null) |0/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python
    (null)|(null)|1|0|N/A|(null)|j1101|no|26612|slurm_py_submit.sh|(null)|UNLIMITED|40K||/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python/slurm_py_submit.sh 1 rcp85 29|0.99998411582782|(null)|Resources||PD|spotter5|(null)|(null)||0|*:*:*|26612 |n/a |1 |1 | |26612 |61101 |* |* |* |N/A |UNLIMITED |0:00 | |0 |myNodes |4294899073 |(Resources) |2019-03-19T13:03:57 |PENDING |474609391 |2018-03-19T11:57:39 |(null) |0/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python
    (null)|(null)|1|0|N/A|(null)|j1101|no|26613|slurm_py_submit.sh|(null)|UNLIMITED|40K||/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python/slurm_py_submit.sh 1 rcp85 30|0.99998411559499|(null)|Resources||PD|spotter5|(null)|(null)||0|*:*:*|26613 |n/a |1 |1 | |26613 |61101 |* |* |* |N/A |UNLIMITED |0:00 | |0 |myNodes |4294899072 |(Resources) |2019-03-19T13:03:57 |PENDING |474609391 |2018-03-19T11:57:39 |(null) |0/att/gpfsfs/home/spotter5/python
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you are asking. Do you have a bunch of 10gb jobs and do you want the queueing system to start new jobs when enough memory is available?

Comment: P.S. It does not seem that the core of your question has much to do with your Python script. Try to make strip all unnecessary parts from your question, to focus only on the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TomdeGeus Yes that is what I want.  So if I have 33 10gb jobs, and I have 3 nodes with 110gb of ram I want to be able to run all 33 at once if possible instead of only 3 at once.

Comment: OK, so please reformulate your question like this.

Comment: But I would expect that the queuing system is smart enough, this seems like a trivial problem. Have you already tried? Also, you may want to use `--mem` instead of `--mem-per-node`

Comment: @TomdeGeus Yes I have run scripts with this and only one job per node  will run with my current bash script.  I have tried `--mem` as well and it is same result

Comment: Can you try with `--ntasks 1` instead of `--ntasks-per-node 1`?

Comment: Also, can you list the status of the queued jobs? (I.e. the output of `squeue`)

Comment: @TomdeGeus I tried with --ntasks 1 and added a picture.

Comment: Great (usually it is best to copy paste BTW). Ok, so it seems that there are no other users, correct? It remains also unclear to me why your jobs are not passing. You could inspect in a bit more detail the jobs and the available resources (for the latter use `sinfo -o "%all"`). Personally I use [some wrappers](https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseSLURM) that could be useful.

Comment: @TomdeGeus I added the return of that command.  Yes I am the only one on this cluster.  I have another cluster as well that more people use and I have never seen two jobs on the same node on there either.

Comment: I any case you might not be doing what you think. The memory claim appears only `40K`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your output of [`sinfo -o "%all"`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html) I can answer why your jobs are not passing.

If you look under the field `CPUS(A/I/O/T)` the output is `16/0/0/16` for all nodes:

- `A`llocated: 16
- `I`dle (available for jobs): 0
- `O`ther: 0
- `T`otal: 16

I.e. somehow the CPUs are the reason for the jobs not passing, not the memory as you expected. All CPUs seem to be allocated by (other) jobs.

Now as to why... For this we currently have insufficient information. The output of `squeue -o "%all"` would give more insight.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, its possible this is an issue on the cluster itself.  I posted the return of `squeue -o "%all"` too though.